# How can I find the k-th largest element in an exponentially large list?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Suppose there are *n* sets of real numbers: `S[1], S[2], ..., S[n]`. We know two things about these sets:

1. Each set S[i] has exactly 3 elements.
2. All elements in each of the sets S[i] are real numbers in the [0, 1] range. (I don't know if this detail can be helpful for the solution, though).

Let's consider a set `T` of all numbers that can be represented as `p[1] * p[2] * p[3] * ... * p[n]` where p[i] is an element of S[i]. This set `T`, obviously, has 3^n elements.

My question is, given the sets `S[1], S[2], ..., S[n]` (1 <= n <= 30) and some 1 <= k <= 10 as input, can we find the k-th largest number in `T` faster than in O(3^n) time? It's important that I need not only the k-th largest number, but also the corresponding numbers (`p[1], p[2], p[3], ... , p[n]`) that produce it.

Even if the answer is no, I would appreciate any hints on how you would solve this problem approximately, maybe, by using some heuristics? I know about [beam search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_search), but maybe you could suggest something else? And even for beam search, it is not really clear how to implement it here the best way.

If the exact answer can be obtained algorithmically in less than O(3^n) time, I would greatly appreciate it if you could point out the solution.

Comment: *"This set T, obviously, has 3^n elements."* It has in the order of 3^n elements. But it's possible that it has fewer elements because some of the products were equal, even if you had some uniqueness hypothesis about the numbers in the S[i] sets.

Comment: Good news: Intuitively I would say "yes we can do much better than 3^n" and bet on an O(kn) solution

Comment: @Stef Yes, sure, there could be repeating numbers. In my case, this is practically unlikely, but theoretically possible.

Comment: @Stef Oh, if there is indeed a solution in polyminal time, that would be super cool:) Could you please share your thoughts or explain why you are confident we can do better?

Comment: I would be really surprised if it was actually unlikely for T to have strictly less than 3^n elements. Unless you have some very strong hypothesis such as "the numbers in the sets S[i] are pairwise coprimes". But that's just nitpicking on my part anyway - the size of T is still exponential in n.

Comment: So one observation is that there's a natural partial ordering on your tuples.  Assuming each `S` is sorted then we can say `(p_1, p_2, ..., p_n) <= (q_1, q_2, ..., q_n)` provided `p_i <= q_i` for all `i`.  `prod` respects this ordering, so if there are > 10 larger tuples in the poset ordering then we know that there are > 10 larger products for that tuple.  Then it takes some combinatorics to figure out how many types of tuples have 10 or fewer larger elements in the poset ordering.

Comment: Well, for instance, "find the largest element of T" is easy: just pick the largest element of each S[i], and the product of those is the largest element of T (assuming all numbers are nonnegative). Then finding the second-largest is a matter of finding which of the factors to change to a slightly smaller factor. Etc. Then again for the third-largest. So it looks like you can find the kth-largest in k steps, and each step should take about n operations

Comment: *"All elements in each of the sets S[i] are real numbers in the [0, 1] range. (I don't know if this detail can be helpful for the solution, though)."* Yes, it is very helpful. The fact that the numbers are less than 1 is probably not important, but the fact that they are nonnegative is very important and avoids having to bother with cumbersome things like "if the number of negative factors is odd then the result is negative; if the number of negative factors is even then the result is positive"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you know that the largest product is the one that uses the largest factor from each set.

Furthermore, every *other* product can be formed by starting with a larger one, and then decreasing the factor chosen in exactly one set.

That leads to a simple search:

1. Put the largest product in a max-first priority queue.
2. Repeat k times:

   a. Remove the largest product p from the priority queue

   b. For each set that has a smaller number than the one selected in p,
   generate the product formed by decreasing that number to the next lower one in that set.  If this selection of factors hasn't been seen before, then add it to the priority queue.

Products will be removed from the queue in decreasing order, so the kth one you take out is the kth largest.

Complexity is about N*(k log kN), depending on how you implement things.

Note that there may be multiple ways to select the factors that produce the same product.  This solution considers those ways to be distinct products, i.e., each way is counted when finding the kth largest.  That may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you didn't make a mistake between largest and smallest? I might be confused but *"Products will be removed from the queue in increasing order, so the kth one you take out is the kth largest."* sounds suspicious

Comment: I did. Fixed :)

Comment: "If it hasn't been seen before, then add it to the priority queue." - this isn't quite right, because even if a product is a duplicate of a previous product, you still need to continue the search through that product.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica. Yes, I am treating each distinct selection of elements as distinct, not each actual product value.

Comment: what is the N here is it the order of 3^n ( n taken from question )?

Comment: @SomeDude it's the number of sets/triples that factors are selected from.

Comment: @MattTimmermans: You may want to clarify that in your answer, then.

Answer (score 2):

To put the previous discussion into code we can do the following:

```
import operator
from functools import partial, reduce
import heapq

def prod_by_data(tup, data):
    return reduce(operator.mul, (datum[t] for t, datum in zip(tup, data)), 1)

def downset(tup):
    return [
        tuple(t - (1 if j == i else 0) for j, t in enumerate(tup))
        for i in range(len(tup))
        if tup[i] > 0
    ]

data = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 2, 1],
    [8, 1, 3],
    [1, 1, 2],
]

data = [sorted(d) for d in data]
prod = partial(prod_by_data, data=data)

k_smallest = [tuple(len(dat) - 1 for dat in data)]
possible_k_smallest = []

while len(k_smallest) < 10:
    new_possible = sorted(downset(k_smallest[-1]), key=prod, reverse=True)
    possible_k_smallest = heapq.merge(possible_k_smallest, new_possible, key=prod, reverse=True)
    k_smallest.append(next(possible_k_smallest))

print(k_smallest)
print([prod(tup) for tup in k_smallest])
```

We maintain a heap of the smallest elements.  After we pop off the smallest, we need to check all if its downset (tuples that differ in exactly one position), because those tuples might be the next smallest element.

We see that we look through `k -  1` times sorting O(n) elements each time with a key that itself is O(n).  Because of the key this should make the sort take O(n^2) instead of O(n log n).  The `heapq` is lazy and so popping from it is actually O(k).  The initial sorting and preparation should be O(n) as well.  Overall I think this makes everything O(k n^2).

Comment: Hey, just a heads up; [`math.prod` is a thing as of 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod), so you don't have to reinvent it from scratch with `functools.reduce` + `operator.mul` anymore.

Comment: Thanks that's good to know.  Another reason to upgrade I suppose, haha.